# How to set a timer to the email sending time with Symfony2 and Swiftmailer

Tags: email, symfony, timer, swiftmailer

Symfony2 uses a [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) bundle to send emails.

In the perspective of creating periodical newsletters, it is interesting to understand if there is any possibility to set a timer to the email sending time. I.e., one prepares the email today and set a timer to let it to be sent tomorrow.

How can I do that in Symfony2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first solution that comes to my mind is to store the newsletters in the database with `publishAt` and `isPublished` fields and create a command that will fetch the newsletters with `NOW() >= publishAt AND isPublished = false`, mail them and set the `isPublished` flag to `true`. The command will be run by cron.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no standard way to schedule periodic emails.

The best way I think is to use something like [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) where you can programmatically manage and schedule mailing campaigns. There is Symfony2 bundle for this - [MZMailChimpBundle](https://github.com/miguel250/MZMailChimpBundle).

If you don't want to use MailChimp (or similar), then the solution by [Elnur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745188) is very good.

Alternatively you can use [mailing queue](http://www.postfix.org/SCHEDULER_README.html), but it is rather advanced topic and it is extra work for your case.